# SQL Data Cleanse - Overlapping Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping someone can help me the best way to resolve this issue.

Our organization currently uses sales cycles to judge the performance of our retailers based on their first shipment date. Here are the business rules:

```
Nurture Stage - 1st year
Graduate Stage - 2nd year
Ongoing Stage - 3rd year and on
Inactive Stage - stop doing business
Restart Stage - do business with us after an Inactive Stage
Change Owner Stage - sell their business and new owner does business with us
```

To complicate this mess, no Retailer can be in the same type of program at any given time. So if they buy a finished product from us, they can't also be in a Program where they buy materials to make it themselves.

```
StageNo   ProgramNo   CustomerNo    ProgramType   StageDescription  StartDate   EndDate

CAPS041835  CAP010611   RL023238    Packaged            Nurture     2019-04-04  2019-04-04    
CAPS041836  CAP010611   RL023238    Packaged            Inactive    2019-04-05  2999-01-01
CAPS041837  CAP010612   RL023238    Pre-Made in Bulk    Nurture     2019-04-04  2999-01-01
```

Above is an example of an anomaly in the data. 01/01/2999 just means it's a blank date in our ERP.

On 04/04/2019, a user created a Packaged Program, and decided the retailer should have been set up for Pre-Made in Bulk instead of Packaged.

The ERP ends the current stage on the last Invoice date, and if non exist, then will end it with today's date, and start the Inactive Stage as of Today + 1.

So If I run analytics, any shipments on 04/04/19 will be applied to both the Packaged and Pre-Made Programs.

Idealy, I would WANT to get rid of the Packaged Program entirely, but if not possible, this is how I'd like to clean it:

```
StageNo   ProgramNo   CustomerNo    ProgramType   StageDescription  StartDate   EndDate

CAPS041835  CAP010611   RL023238    Packaged            Nurture     2019-04-04  2019-04-04    
CAPS041836  CAP010611   RL023238    Packaged            Inactive    2019-04-04  2019-04-04
CAPS041837  CAP010612   RL023238    Pre-Made in Bulk    Nurture     2019-04-04  2999-01-01
```

I can go through and fix it once it's like this. Even if I left it, it wouldn't be the end of the world because I can cast the shipment date as DateTime, and then +1 second, which means the sale will only fall in 1 Program.

I started by writing a query to find the gaps between the date ranges to find any gaps where the date diff is less than 0.

This is what I have so far...

```
WITH CustomerProgram AS 
(
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [CustomerNo] ASC, [ProgramGroupId] ASC, [StageStartDate] ASC, [StageEndDate] ASC, [StagePrecedence] ASC, [CustomerProgramStageNo] ASC) AS [RowId]
        ,*
        ,COUNT([CustomerProgramStageNo]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ProgramGroupId]) AS [StageCount]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
             --RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [CustomerNo] ASC, [ProgramDescription] ASC) AS [ProgramGroupId]
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [CustomerNo] ASC, [CustomerProgramNo] ASC) AS [ProgramGroupId]
            ,[CustomerProgramNo]
            ,[CustomerProgramStageNo]
            ,[CustomerNo]
            ,[ProgramCode]
            ,[ProgramStageCode]
            ,[ProgramStageDescription]
            ,CASE [ProgramStageDescription]
                WHEN 'Nurture'          THEN 1
                WHEN 'Graduate'         THEN 2
                WHEN 'Change Ownership' THEN 3
                WHEN 'Restart'          THEN 3
                WHEN 'Ongoing'          THEN 4
                WHEN 'Inactive'         THEN 5
                ELSE NULL
            END                                 AS [StagePrecedence]
            ,CAST([StageStartDate] AS DATETIME) AS [StageStartDate]
            ,CAST([StageEndDate] AS DATETIME)   AS [StageEndDate]
        FROM
            [CustomerProgramAndStage]
    )   CustomerProgram
)

,StagesAndGaps AS 
(
    SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [CustomerNo] ASC, [ProgramGroupId] ASC, [StageStartDate] ASC, [StageEndDate] ASC) AS [RowId]
        ,[ProgramGroupId]
        ,[StageCount]
        ,[CustomerNo]
        ,[DateRangeType]
        ,[StageStartDate]
        ,[StageEndDate]
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY,[StageStartDate],[StageEndDate])  AS [StageDateDayDiff]
        ,DATEDIFF(YEAR,[StageStartDate],[StageEndDate]) AS [StageDateYearDiff]
        ,[StartDateRowId]
        ,[EndDateRowId]
        ,[PreviousProgramCode]
        ,[NextProgramCode]
        ,[PreviousStagePrecedence]
        ,[NextStagePrecedence]
        ,[PreviousStageNo]
        ,[NextStageNo]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
             [ProgramGroupId]                           AS [ProgramGroupId]
            ,[StageCount]                               AS [StageCount]
            ,[CustomerNo]                               AS [CustomerNo]
            ,[DateRangeType]                            AS [DateRangeType]
            ,ISNULL([StageStartDate],'1800-01-01')      AS [StageStartDate]
            ,ISNULL([StageEndDate],'3999-01-01')        AS [StageEndDate]
            ,ISNULL([StartDateRowId],0)                 AS [StartDateRowId]
            ,ISNULL([EndDateRowId],9999999)             AS [EndDateRowId]
            ,ISNULL([PreviousProgramCode],'Start')      AS [PreviousProgramCode]
            ,ISNULL([NextProgramCode],'End')            AS [NextProgramCode]
            ,ISNULL([PreviousStagePrecedence],0)        AS [PreviousStagePrecedence]
            ,ISNULL([NextStagePrecedence],999)          AS [NextStagePrecedence]
            ,ISNULL([PreviousStageNo],'Start')          AS [PreviousStageNo]
            ,ISNULL([NextStageNo],'End')                AS [NextStageNo]
        FROM
        (
            SELECT --  Gaps include time period before the start of a Program
                 NextStage.[ProgramGroupId]                 AS [ProgramGroupId]
                ,NextStage.[StageCount]                     AS [StageCount]
                ,NextStage.[CustomerNo]                     AS [CustomerNo]
                ,'Gap'                                      AS [DateRangeType]
                ,PreviousStage.[StageEndDate]               AS [StageStartDate]
                ,NextStage.[StageStartDate]                 AS [StageEndDate]
                ,PreviousStage.[RowId]                      AS [StartDateRowId]
                ,NextStage.[RowId]                          AS [EndDateRowId]
                ,PreviousStage.[ProgramCode]                AS [PreviousProgramCode]
                ,NextStage.[ProgramCode]                    AS [NextProgramCode]
                ,PreviousStage.[StagePrecedence]            AS [PreviousStagePrecedence]
                ,NextStage.[StagePrecedence]                AS [NextStagePrecedence]
                ,PreviousStage.[CustomerProgramStageNo]     AS [PreviousStageNo]
                ,NextStage.[CustomerProgramStageNo]         AS [NextStageNo]
            FROM
            (
                SELECT
                     [RowId]
                    ,[ProgramGroupId]
                    ,[StageCount]
                    ,[CustomerProgramStageNo]
                    ,[CustomerNo]
                    ,[ProgramCode]
                    ,[StagePrecedence]
                    ,[StageStartDate]
                FROM
                    CustomerProgram
            )   NextStage    
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                     [RowId]
                    ,[ProgramGroupId]
                    ,[StageCount]
                    ,[CustomerProgramStageNo]
                    ,[CustomerNo]
                    ,[ProgramCode]
                    ,[StagePrecedence]
                    ,[StageEndDate]
                FROM
                    CustomerProgram
            )   PreviousStage
                    ON NextStage.[ProgramGroupId] = PreviousStage.[ProgramGroupId]
                    AND NextStage.[RowId] - 1 = PreviousStage.[RowId]

            UNION

            SELECT --  Gaps include time period after the end of a Program (year 2999 if Stage is active)
                 PreviousStage.[ProgramGroupId]             AS [ProgramGroupId]
                ,PreviousStage.[StageCount]                 AS [StageCount]
                ,PreviousStage.[CustomerNo]                 AS [CustomerNo]
                ,'Gap'                                      AS [DateRangeType]
                ,PreviousStage.[StageEndDate]               AS [StageStartDate]
                ,NextStage.[StageStartDate]                 AS [StageEndDate]
                ,PreviousStage.[RowId]                      AS [StartDateRowId]
                ,NextStage.[RowId]                          AS [EndDateRowId]
                ,PreviousStage.[ProgramCode]                AS [PreviousProgramCode]
                ,NextStage.[ProgramCode]                    AS [NextProgramCode]
                ,PreviousStage.[StagePrecedence]            AS [PreviousStagePrecedence]
                ,NextStage.[StagePrecedence]                AS [NextStagePrecedence]
                ,PreviousStage.[CustomerProgramStageNo]     AS [PreviousStageNo]
                ,NextStage.[CustomerProgramStageNo]         AS [NextStageNo]
            FROM
            (
                SELECT
                     [RowId]
                    ,[ProgramGroupId]
                    ,[StageCount]
                    ,[CustomerProgramStageNo]
                    ,[CustomerNo]
                    ,[ProgramCode]
                    ,[StagePrecedence]
                    ,[StageEndDate]
                FROM
                    CustomerProgram
            )   PreviousStage
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                     [RowId]
                    ,[ProgramGroupId]
                    ,[StageCount]
                    ,[CustomerProgramStageNo]
                    ,[CustomerNo]
                    ,[ProgramCode]
                    ,[StagePrecedence]
                    ,[StageStartDate]
                FROM
                    CustomerProgram
            )   NextStage
                    ON PreviousStage.[ProgramGroupId] = NextStage.[ProgramGroupId]
                    AND PreviousStage.[RowId] + 1 = NextStage.[RowId]

            UNION

            SELECT --  Stage data
                 [ProgramGroupId]           AS [ProgramGroupId]
                ,[StageCount]               AS [StageCount]
                ,[CustomerNo]               AS [CustomerNo]
                ,'Stage'                    AS [DateRangeType]
                ,[StageStartDate]           AS [StageStartDate]
                ,[StageEndDate]             AS [StageEndDate]
                ,[RowId]                    AS [StartDateRowId]
                ,[RowId]                    AS [EndDateRowId]
                ,[ProgramCode]              AS [PreviousProgramCode]
                ,[ProgramCode]              AS [NextProgramCode]
                ,[StagePrecedence]          AS [PreviousStagePrecedence]
                ,[StagePrecedence]          AS [NextStagePrecedence]
                ,[CustomerProgramStageNo]   AS [PreviousStageNo]
                ,[CustomerProgramStageNo]   AS [NextStageNo]
            FROM
                CustomerProgram
        )   StagesAndGaps
    )   StagesAndGaps
)


SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    StagesAndGaps
WHERE 
    [DateRangeType] = 'Gap'
    AND [StageStartDate] NOT IN ('1800-01-01','2999-01-01')
ORDER BY 
    [RowId] ASC
```

I think I'm headed in the right direction, but I'm also not sure if there is an easier way. Sorry for the long post, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Getting rid of the packaged program will be easier than updating is what I feel. And, that is what will leave the system in a better state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PARTITION, ORDER to divide the dataset into ordered chunks and then identify records which needs to be updated/deleted, which is what you have tried. But, you can be more precise.

For example, you have just used ORDER BY which will give you:

row_num customer_no stage stage_startdate
1       1           A     2019-01-01
2       2           B     2019-12-30

Here, you can't compare row_num 1 and 2, because they both belong to two different customers.

So, use PARTITION first to divide the chunks and then use ORDER BY to arrange the data.

And, instead of updating you can go for marking unwanted records and then deleting them.

For that, add 'to_be_deleted' column to mark the records which needs to be deleted. If you are using SQL Server 2012+, this 'to_be_deleted' column can be easily populated using LEAD() or LAG() on top of PARTITION output. LEAD() or LAG() functions help you to compare with previous or next rows. So, you can easily check for duplicates and then mark them, which can eventually be deleted.

You can refer to this for LEAD(), LAG(): https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Hope this helps you :). Good initiative by the way

Comment: Thanks for the response! In the CustomerProgram CTE, there's a nested query with a field called ProgramGroupId. I used RANK to create groups, with the idea that the first Stage would always be RowId = ProgramGroupId. Bad design. I should have used an ORDER BY StartDate, not CustomerProgramNo. After I posted my question, I actually went back and added a PARTITION instead. But I think the LEAD() LAG() is exactly what I need! I'm working in a 2008 R2 database, but I think I'll load the data into the warehouse and manipulate it there. Thank you so much for the help! I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: By the way, I gave you a positive vote (I think that's what it's called) but I have less than 15 reputations so it's saying that it was recorded but it won't be visible to the public. I need to stop being such a noob and get on here more often! Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. Good luck

Comment: If lead(), lag() doesnt work, you can go for row_num() based on partition and ordering and then left join with the same table's previous row_num and next row_num to get what you want.